# Ember.js Computed Property vs Observer vs didReceiveAttrs() in a Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, observers, ember-components, computed-properties

I have created a top navbar in my ember.js application and converted it to a component so that I can have a simple "Welcome {{currentUser.fullName}}" introduction once a user signs in.  There are some other reasons why the navbar is going to be a component, but for now this is what I am trying to get working correctly.  We are also using ember-simple-auth addon and I am using the `session.isAuthenticated` value to make this happen.

Of course I have a 'login' route, that when the user signs in, they are transitioned to the 'index'.  For some reason it doesn't seem like the `session.isAuthenticated` value is caught right away during the transition to the 'index'.  I don't know why this is, but that is another issue.

Anyway, I am using a lot of components in this application and most of those components get their values from the sessions and querying the store independently of the routes so that I can use these components on multiple routes.  The navbar is no exception.  Right now I have the following working code:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
    isAuthenticated: Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        this.didReceiveAttrs();
    }),
    currentUserFullName: null,
    user: null,
    tagName: 'navbar-main',
    className: ['navbar', 'main'],
    didReceiveAttrs() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
            this._setCurrentUser();
        }
    },
    _setCurrentUser() {
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    },
    onGetCurrentUser: Ember.observer('user', function() {
        this.getUser();
    }),
    getUser: function() {
        var user = this.get('user');

        if(user) {
            this.set('user', user);
            this.set('currentUserFullName', user.get('fullName'));
        } else {
            user = this.get('store').findRecord('user', 'me');
            this.set('user', user);
            this.set('currentUserFullName', user.get('fullName'));
        }
    }
});
```

Everything I am reading suggests to just use `didReceiveAttrs()` instead of an observer.  Also, it says that computed properties are usually what you want to use over observers. However I can't seem to get anything to work without the following:

```
isAuthenticated: Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
    this.didReceiveAttrs();
}),
```

If I try to convert it to a computed property it doesn't seem to do anything on a property change unless I refresh the page after it has already transitioned to the 'index' route.  If I try to use just the `didReceiveAttrs()` method with this.get('session.isAuthenticated') logic, a page refresh is still needed.

So what am I not understanding about how to use `Ember.computed`and `didReceiveAttrs()`?  Can someone give me an example? Or show me a more efficient way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

UPDATED CODE:

```
// app/pods/components/navbar-main/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from './template'; 

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
    user: null,
    isAuthenticated: Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    }),
    currentUserFullName: Ember.computed.alias('user.fullName'),
    tagName: 'navbar-main',
    className: ['navbar', 'main'],
    didReceiveAttrs() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
            this.isAuthenticated();
        }
    }
});

<!-- app/pods/components/navbar-main/template.hbs -->
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
    <div class="ui black user login label">
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="twelve wide column">
                <div class="detailed">{{currentUserFullName}}<br>Welcome</div>
            </div>
            <div class="four wide column" style="padding-top: 12px; margin-top: 0;">
                <img class="ui top aligned small avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/christian.jpg">
                <!--<img class="ui top aligned tiny avatar image" src="{{currentUser.avatar}}">-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

UPDATE 2 (Final code with help from @AdamCooper and @kumkanillam):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
    user: null,
    isAuthenticated: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    })),
    currentUserFullName: Ember.computed.alias('user.fullName'),
    tagName: 'navbar-main',
    className: ['navbar', 'main']
});
```

So this is the least amount of code, still using observer and computed methods, but not using the component lifecycle.  So I guess it is still necessary to use observers sometimes is what I have come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with that worked for my situation:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
    user: null,
    isAuthenticated: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    })),
    currentUserFullName: Ember.computed.alias('user.fullName'),
    tagName: 'navbar-main',
    className: ['navbar', 'main']
});
```

This is using a combination of [Ember Freak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771666/ember-freak)'s and [Adam Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529475/adam-cooper)'s answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule you want to avoid the use of observers whenever possible. Steffan Penner has a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PUX27RKCq0) on observers that I would recommend you watch to truly understand why they are potentially hazardous to your codebase.

In your case the load() function is returning a promise which is not something you want to return from a computed property so you will need to use an observer on isAuthenticated. 
I've simplified your code as much as I can without being able to run it, but hopefully you should get the idea:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),

    user: null,

    authenticatedObserver: Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        // Load the user, this will cause the currentUserFullName to be 
        // updated. We're using an observer here because load() returns
        // a promise 
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    }),

    // This computed property will be re-calculated whenever user is modified
    currentUserFullName: Ember.computed.alias('user.fullName')  
});
```

Comment: ~ so that is basically the same thing I have already heard and read about observers, yet your answer still uses an observer?  lol.  Can I assume that this particular situation needs to use an observer?

Comment: I only use an observer where I have to. That is where you are calling out to the load function

Comment: So this works if I still use `didReceiveAttrs() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
            this.isAuthenticated();
        }
    },`, which does definitely shorten the code, but I am still unsure of what is really going on because if I do a `this.get('currentUserFullName')' or a `this.get('user')`, I get null values.  I also have to change my template to `{{#if session.isAuthenticated` instead of `{#if currentUser` to hide the element that this is tied to. Does this sound right?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have now

Comment: Ok, I added the suggestion from @kumkanillam, so it was more of a joint effort between the two of you, but this answer was the closest.  My updated code is above that works.

Answer (score 2):

Ember will call components life cycle hook methods in the order according to rendering scenario.

On initial render - *init,didReceiveAttrs,willRender,didInsertElement,didRender*
On Re-Rener - *didUpdateAttrs,didReceiveAttrs,willUpdate,willRender,didRender*
On Component destroy - *willDestroyElement,willClearRender,didDestroyElement*
(Reference - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)

We should not call those component life cycle hook methods.

I beleive,you can completely isolate currentUser specific code to currentUser service, so that you can easily inject and use it for all your components.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
    currentUserFullName: Ember.computed.alias('currentUser.currentUserFullName'),
    user: Ember.computed.alias('currentUser.user'),

    tagName: 'navbar-main',
    className: ['navbar', 'main'],    

});
```

Initialize currentUser and their details by observing session.isAuthenticated property.

**services\current-user.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  currentUserFullName: null,
  user: null,

  loadCurrentUserDetails:Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function(){
    //load async data and set user and currentUserFullName.
  })
});
```

Comment: ~ I was wondering about initializing, but haven't really touched on the initializers yet. I will look into this and comment back.

Comment: I am actually using a ember addon node package with my project that already has a service for currentUser, so this wasn't working for me.  I don't want to change the service that this is tied to, but that service is using a computed property: `currentUserId: Ember.computed('session.data.authenticated', function() {var session = this.get('session'); if (session.get('isAuthenticated')) {return session.get('data.authenticated.id'); } else {return null;}}),`

Comment: And then: `load() {return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {var currentUserId = this.get('currentUserId');if (currentUserId) {var currentUser = this.get('store').peekRecord('user', currentUserId);if (currentUser) {resolve(currentUser);} else {this.get('store').findRecord('user', currentUserId).then((user) => resolve(user), reject);}} else {reject();}});}`, So using this already pre-existing service I used @AdamCooper s suggestion above and still added a `didReceiveAttrs()` function to get it to work (explained above).  Is this the best way?

Comment: No you should not call `didReceiveAttrs()` IMHO. Observers never fire until after the initialization of an object is complete. [Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-object-initialization) .  You could try this .. `isAuthenticated: Ember.on('init',Ember.observer('session.isAuthenticated', function() {
        this.get('currentUser').load().then(user => this.set('user', user));
    }))`

Comment: ~ Thank you very much!  This did the trick.  I updated my post.